# How to detect EOF on a SOCK_DGRAM socketpair

Tags: sockets, unix, network-programming

I'm trying to detect EOF on the endpoint of a socketpair of type SOCK_DGRAM but select never returns:

```
let (sock1, sock2) = Unix.socketpair Unix.PF_UNIX Unix.SOCK_DGRAM 0
let () = Unix.shutdown sock1 Unix.SHUTDOWN_ALL
let () = Unix.close sock1
let (rw, _, _) = Unix.select [sock2] [] [sock2] (-1.)
```

Strace output:

```
socketpair(PF_FILE, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, [3, 4]) = 0
shutdown(3, 2 /* send and receive */)   = 0
close(3)                                = 0
select(5, [4], [], [4], NULL
```

Note: As SOCK_STREAM this works. But not SOCK_DGRAM.

So how do I detect EOF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOCK_DGRAM isn't connection oriented, and doesn't give you the ability to detect that the other end is closed.

(If you're on linux, and possibly other systems, you can use SOCK_SEQPACKET, which is connection oriented and allows one end to detect when the other end is closed while still maintaining datagram delimited data).

Comment: Shutdown on a UDP socket doesn't do anything either.

Comment: ^^ what @EJP says.  You bind and datagrams turn up..or not.  No connection/disconnect/shutdown/whatever is either required or possible with UDP.